# How to display IntegerField in django admin?

Tags: django

How to display IntegerField in django admin?

My error: **coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found**

```
class Day(models.Model):
    day = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.day
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to return a string, not an integer. like this:

```
return str(self.day)
```